# What exactly is banned if the US bans on several Chinese apps go into effect?

Tags: united-states, internet, software

President Trump issued several executive orders, banning certain Chinese-owned apps in 45 days if they are still owned by their original companies (as I understand it):

- [EO 13942](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/2020-17699) (August 6, 2020) - TikTok
- [EO 13943](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/2020-17700) (August 6, 2020) - WeChat
- [EO 13971](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/2021-00305) (January 5, 2021) - Alipay, CamScanner, QQ Wallet, SHAREit, Tencent QQ, VMate, WeChat Pay, and WPS Office

These executive orders were revoked by [EO 14034](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/2021-12506).

The Commerce Department published regulations on the bans:

- [Prohibited transactions with TikTok](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/09/24/2020-21193/identification-of-prohibited-transactions-to-implement-executive-order-13942-and-address-the-threat), temporarily blocked by [this injunction](https://www.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.paed.575844/gov.uscourts.paed.575844.36.0_1.pdf) and this injunction (part [1](https://www.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.dcd.222257/gov.uscourts.dcd.222257.29.0_8_1.pdf) and [2](https://www.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.dcd.222257/gov.uscourts.dcd.222257.59.0_2.pdf))
- Prohibited transactions with WeChat (withdrawn, archived at Exhibit A [here](https://www.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.cand.364733/gov.uscourts.cand.364733.45.1.pdf)), temporarily blocked by [an injunction](https://www.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.cand.364733/gov.uscourts.cand.364733.59.0.pdf).

Both of these regulations were [rescinded](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2021/06/23/2021-13156/rescission-of-identification-of-prohibited-transactions-with-respect-to-tiktok-and-wechat).

Hypothetically, if one of these bans had gone into effect, what would have been the actual effect on an app user?

1. Would app stores be required to remove the apps from the app store for users in the US?
2. Would app stores run by US companies (e.g. Apple iOS app store, Google Play for Android) be required to remove the apps from the app store for users outside the US?
3. Would it be illegal for a user in the US to download the app somehow from outside the app store?
4. Would it be illegal for a user in the US to use the app if they have already downloaded it?
5. Would it be illegal (under US law) for a US citizen outside the US to download and/or use the app?
6. Would ISPs in the US be required to try to block network traffic of the app?

Comment: If you haven't seen it, there's a more detailed, but readable, article on Lawfare. It agrees we don't know the answers yet. It also points out: 1) Since TikTok will likely be sold to MS, it's probably not going to be an issue; and, 2) TenCent, WeChat's parent, is a *huge* problem. It owns a lot of stuff in the US, including chunks of *Tesla,* *Spotify,* *Reddit,* and "Call of Duty*! And unlike TitTok, there's no easy offramp for WeChat. https://www.lawfareblog.com/banning-tiktok-and-wechat-another-primer

Answer (score 4):

I will try to answer some of my questions based on recent developments and other information I've seen.

1. Yes. 2. No.

On page 23 of [this Commerce Dept. memo on TikTok](https://www.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.dcd.222257/gov.uscourts.dcd.222257.22.1.pdf), it describes:

> This prohibition would remove the TikTok app from U.S.-based mobile
> app stores, preventing mobile users from being able to download the
> app to their devices or receive updates.  As scoped, this prohibition
> would only apply to app stores accessible in the United States, thus
> users would still be able to download the app while outside the United
> States.

On page 15 of [this Commerce Dept. memo on WeChat](https://www.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.cand.364733/gov.uscourts.cand.364733.76.1.pdf), it describes:

> This prohibition would remove the WeChat app from U.S.-based mobile
> app stores, preventing mobile users from being able to download the
> app to their devices or receive updates.  As scoped, this prohibition
> would only apply to app stores accessible in the United States, thus
> users would still be able to download the app while outside the United
> States.

3,4,5. No for WeChat. In letters sent to the [opposite party](https://www.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.cand.364733/gov.uscourts.cand.364733.31.1.pdf) in a lawsuit and filed with [the court](https://www.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.cand.364733/gov.uscourts.cand.364733.31.0.pdf), the US government has provided assurances that WeChat users will not have any civil or criminal liability for downloading or using the app for personal or business communication.

> we can provide assurances that the Secretary does not intend to take
> actions that would target persons or groups whose only connection with
> WeChat is their use or downloading of the app to convey personal or
> business information between users, or otherwise define the relevant
> transactions in such a way that would impose criminal or civil
> liability on such users.  In other words, while use of the app for
> such communications could be directly or indirectly impaired through
> measures targeted at other transactions, use and downloading of the
> app for this limited purpose will not be a defined transaction, and
> such users will not be targeted or subject to penalties.

I'm not entirely sure for TikTok, but the same may be true for TikTok since the prohibited transactions for both are essentially the same.

6. No. The regulations on prohibited transactions do not require the blocking of traffic from the apps. Simply carrying the traffic of the app is not one of the prohibited transactions, as long as the company does not have a contract for internet transit or peering with ByteDance/Tencent, nor are providing hosting or content delivery services to ByteDance/Tencent.

   On page 23 of the Commerce Dept. memo on TikTok linked above, it says:

> User data could still be served by data centers, [redacted] operating
> outside of the United States.

On page 7 of [this declaration](https://www.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.cand.364733/gov.uscourts.cand.364733.93.1.pdf) by a Commerce Dept. official further explains that WeChat traffic will still flow through the US:

> Moreover, this prohibition would not affect Internet transit or
> peering services in the United States that are not “directly
> contracted or arranged” by Tencent, and thus would leave the
> overwhelming majority of Internet traffic, including WeChat data,
> untouched.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently unknown exactly how this will play out. The law allows POTUS to prohibit transactions with Bytedance and subsidiaries, including Bytedance property (such as, their app). Evading the order, or conspiring to evade, is prohibited. The Secretary of Commerce can promulgate regulations to implement the order.

The restrictions would apply to all US humans (citizens and otherwise) and US companies (Google, Apple). Being outside the US is not relevant, but being completely unconnected to the US is (i.e. Kazakhstani company and Kazakhstani citizen). Enforcement would be strictly at the hands of the federal government (assuming that states don't implement such a ban on their own). Although we can't know what the regulations will be, the likely answer to your questions is "yes", though "required to block network traffic" might be most vulnerable to legal attack. The law allows "blocking transactions"; what you describe is reasonably related to "blocking transactions", and seems clearly within the scope of what Congress has allowed.

The [rule as of Sept. 18](https://s3.amazonaws.com/public-inspection.federalregister.gov/2020-20920.pdf) immediately (i.e. "when officially published", in 4+ days) prohibits

> Any transaction by any person, or with respect to any property...with
> ByteDance... in which any such company has any interest, involving:
>
> Any provision of services to distribute or maintain the TikTok mobile
> application... through an online mobile application store

A second phase starts Nov 12 which prohibits

> provision of internet hosting services enabling the functioning or
> optimization of the TikTok mobile application
>
> ...
>
> directly contracted or arranged internet transit or peering services
> enabling the functioning or optimization
>
> ...
>
> content delivery network services enabling the functioning or
> optimization
>
> ...
>
> utilization of the TikTok mobile application’s constituent code,
> functions, or services in the functioning of software or services

or any other transaction with the company. In other words, my phone company (I guess) has to filter out TikTok traffic. Also note that

> The identified prohibitions herein only apply to the parties to
> business-to-business transactions

and specifically it does not forbid paying employees and contractors, and does not forbid

> The exchange between or among TikTok mobile application users of
> personal or business information using the TikTok mobile application;

or

> storing of TikTok mobile application user data in the United States

and it only applies in the US.

Comment: I have updated the question with links to the Commerce Department regulations. Can you update your answer given that information?

Answer (score 0):

**It depends on how the government try to enact this executive order.**

(Further interesting article on IEEPA and the EO [here](https://www.lawfareblog.com/could-tiktok-and-wechat-executive-orders-undermine-ieepa) from a Harvard Lecturer)

> Article Two of the United States Constitution gives the president
> broad executive and enforcement authority to use their discretion to
> determine how to enforce the law or to otherwise manage the resources
> and staff of the executive branch. The ability to make such orders is
> also based on express or implied Acts of Congress that delegate to the
> President some degree of discretionary power (delegated legislation). ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_order))

Executive orders (EO's) may be enforced by all levels of state government. For example, state attorneys general offices can act through their own authority, seek assistance from state law enforcement, utilize the courts and judicial system, and work with state agencies that have particular policy concerns or interests. Also, county governments can enforce these orders by acting through their officials and agencies, such as county health departments and county sheriffs. See [here](https://www.jdsupra.com/legalnews/state-and-local-enforcement-of-60352/#:%7E:text=Executive%20orders%20may%20be%20enforced,particular%20policy%20concerns%20or%20interests.).

Specific issues in law, are often tested as and when they present themselves. With specific reference to the EO related to 'TikTok' ([here](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/executive-order-addressing-threat-posed-tiktok/)).

Section one has stated:

> The following actions shall be prohibited beginning 45 days after the
> date of this order, to the extent permitted under applicable law: any
> transaction by any person, or with respect to any property, subject to
> the jurisdiction of the United States, with ByteDance Ltd. (a.k.a.
> Zìjié Tiàodòng), Beijing, China, or its subsidiaries, in which any
> such company has any interest, as identified by the Secretary of
> Commerce (Secretary) under section 1(c) of this order.

So - pending section 1(c) - which would see the Secretary of Commence identify which 'transactions' that were considered relevant to this EO.

> 45 days after the date of this order, the Secretary shall identify the transactions subject to subsection (a) of this section.

Then specifically, it authorises the S. for Commence to take actions to implement the EO, we can see Sec. 4:

> The Secretary is hereby authorized to take such actions, including
> adopting rules and regulations, and to employ all powers granted to me
> by IEEPA as may be necessary to implement this order.  The Secretary
> may, consistent with applicable law, redelegate any of these functions
> within the Department of Commerce.  All departments and agencies of
> the United States shall take all appropriate measures within their
> authority to implement this order.

So ultimately, with reference to your points:

> Would app stores be required to remove the apps from the app store for users in the US?

Potentially, if this was mandated by the relevant secretary after the 45 days.

---

> Would app stores run by US companies (e.g. Apple iOS app store, Google Play for Android) be required to remove the apps from the app store for users outside the US?

Users outside the US are not subject to the laws of the US - so they could, theoretically still download the app if it is hosted on servers external to the US. It would probably not be allowed if the app was downloaded on a solely US server. This will again depend on how the Executive Order is legislated for by the secretary/agents of the US government. ("the Secretary shall identify the transactions subject to subsection (a) of this section")

---

> Would it be illegal for a user in the US to download the app somehow from outside the app store?

Yes due to: "Sec. 2.  (a)  Any transaction by a United States person or within the United States that evades or avoids, has the purpose of evading or avoiding, causes a violation of, or attempts to violate the prohibition set forth in this order is prohibited."

---

> Would it be illegal for a user in the US to use the app if they have already downloaded it?

Again, depends on how the secretary enacts this executive order. But, most likely.

---

> Would it be illegal (under US law) for a US citizen outside the US to download and/or use the app?

This is difficult to legislate for - as once outside of US jurisdiction, you are subject to the laws of the land in which you are present. It may well be made illegal via US law, but unenforceable, for example, if the US citizen was in the UK. Ultimately, it is considered that US law applies domestically: see [here](https://assets.corporatecompliance.org/Portals/1/691_0_us_jurisdictionabroad.pdf).

---

> Would ISPs in the US be required to try to block network traffic of the app?

This depends on how the secretary implements the executive order. They could pass a requirement that this happens, pursuant to the executive order. "All departments and agencies of the United States shall take all appropriate measures within their authority to implement this order."

As with everything legal, this is nuanced and develops over time. The enforcement and enacting of an executive order depends on the actions of many government departments.

Comment: In the context of the International Emergency Economic Powers Act, what exactly is the definition of "transaction", such that installing or using the TikTok software would be a transaction?  And in what statute or case law is it defined?

Comment: This is why it depends on the follow-on laws or regulations created by the relevant secretary of state that are created from this Executive Order. In the IEEPA - it seems to mostly be concerned with economic/financial transactions: https://fas.org/sgp/crs/natsec/R45618.pdf - its statute and purview is discussed here also in this long document!

Comment: So legislative history and the intent of the authors of the IEEPA place limits on how far a secretary of state can stretch the definition of "transaction"?

Comment: It's a really interesting train of thought. I would have thought so - but ultimately, that would have to be argued via the judicial system and legislature.

Comment: @MatthewCline The Secretary of Commerce does not have to rely on “transactions.” 50 USC § 1702(b), also gives the President the power to control any “acquisition, holding…use, transfer, ,.. or importation of” any property controlled by a foreign national. Since TikTok uses servers in the US, users may not be “importing,” but they are surely “acquiring, holding, using or transferring” TikTok.

Comment: @Justaguy The current executive order says "any transaction by any person, or with respect to any property".  Assuming the EO isn't amended, would "or with respect to any property" allow the use of the "acquiring, holding, using or transferring” part of the IEEPA?

Comment: Good spot @Justaguy - have made some further amendments!

Comment: @DrDee Nice work, and welcome to LSE! You are off to a flying start.

Comment: @MatthewCline *Mea culpa.* You are absolutely right! My bad for not looking at the EO before posting. I don't think the "trick" you suggest will get us to "use..." There are two problems. First, "or with respect to..." clearly modifies "transaction." That phrase says the P can control any "transactions" a) by people who the US has jurisdiction over, or b) involving property that the US has jurisdiction over. We'd have to do some work to "stretch" the property phrase back past "transaction" to "use..."

Comment: @MatthewCline (Con't) Here’s the problem: The list of activities the P can control is *disjunctive* -- the various activities are joined by "*or.*” The general rule is that the items on disjunctive lists shouldn’t be treated as synonyms. Treating them as synonyms violates the "canon against superfluity,” an interpretive rule that says you can't interpret a law so any of its words are superfluous. If “transaction” includes all the other words on the list, what’s the point of list?

Comment: @MatthewCline My hunch is that if pressed, the P's lawyers will point out that "transaction" has broader definitions. Implicit in this is the fact (threat? promise?) that the P could solve this particular problem by issuing a new EO, explicitly mentioning "use." It is telling that so far, none of the credible legal commentators, many of whom oppose the EO, have noted this problem. This suggests that, as a matter of *law-as-what-lawyers-do,* "transaction" isn't a problem. (TenCent, which has a lot more at stake, might be desperate enough to raise this issue.)

Comment: @Justaguy - thank you for the welcome and constructive feedback! :-) This place is a phenomenal resource.

Comment: Interesting article published yesterday here: https://www.lawfareblog.com/could-tiktok-and-wechat-executive-orders-undermine-ieepa

Comment: @DrDee American and real English also uses the same words differently in academic titles. Thus, a lecturer in the US is not the same as a lecturer in the UK. In the UK, lecturer is the lowest "real" academic position; one can work permanently as a lecturer. Not so in the US. In the US, a lecturer is *generally* temporary, and not on a job ladder that leads to tenure. So the fact that someone is a "lecturer" at Harvard is usually not worth noting in the same way it might be in the UK.

Comment: I have updated the question with links to the Commerce Department regulations. Can you update your answer given that information?